# Necesito sacar algunos elementos de esta lista PYTHON

Tags: python

Necesito sacar de la lista(`listaCoefX`) definida abajo los valores en este formato:

```
lista=[[-2,+1,-1,+2],[-2,+2,-1,-0],[0,+0,+2,+2],[0,+0,+0,+4]
```

esto llevo del código para hacer lo que solicito:

```
  listaCoefX=['-2X1+1X2-1X3+2X4', '-2X1+2X2-1X3+0X4', '0X1+0X2+2X3-2X4','0X1+0X2+0X3+4X4']

def extraerValores(listadeEc):
    lista3=[]
    lista2=[]
    for i in listadeEc:
        print "i= ",i
        aux=list(i)
        print "aux= ", aux
        lista2.append(aux)
    for i in lista2:
        while "X" in i :
            i.remove("X")
    for i in lista2:
        i.reverse()
    j=0
    while j<len(lista2):
        valor=lista2[j]
        k=0
        while k<len(valor):
            valor.pop(k)
            k=k+2

        j=j+1
    for i in lista2:
         i.reverse()
```

Comment: si alguna de las respuestas ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta  (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Answer (score 2):

Como ya te comente en otra pregunta te estas complicando la vida, con expresiones regulares es mucho mas fácil y limpio. Otro ejemplo en 2 lineas (una si no compilas la expresion regular):

```
import re

listaCoefX=['-2X1+1X2-1X3+2X4', '-2X1+2X2-1X3+0X4', '0X1+0X2+2X3-2X4','0X1+0X2+0X3+4X4']

patt = re.compile('([+-]?[\d]*)(X[\d]*)')
res = [[int(coef[0]) for coef in re.findall(patt, ecuacion)] for ecuacion in listaCoefX]

print res
```

Esto ya te da la matriz con los coeficiente pasados a enteros:

```
[[-2, 1, -1, 2], [-2, 2, -1, 0], [0, 0, 2, -2], [0, 0, 0, 4]]
```

**Actualización:**

Como dice @Mariano en los comentarios de esta respuesta, se puede simplificar más:

```
import re

listaCoefX=['-2X1+1X2-1X3+2X4', '-2X1+2X2-1X3+0X4', '0X1+0X2+2X3-2X4','0X1+0X2+0X3+4X4']

patt = re.compile('([+-]?\d*)X')
res = [[int(coef) for coef in re.findall(patt, ecuacion)] for ecuacion in   listaCoefX]

print res
```

Cambiando la expresión `'([+-]?[\d])(X[\d])'` por `'([+-]?\d*)X'`. La diferencia es que la primera (al usarla en el método `findall()`) nos da una tupla en la que el primer elemento es el coeficiente y el segundo la variable, es decir, para la primera ecuación retornaria algo asi:

```
[('-2', 'X1'), ('+1', 'X2'), ('-1', 'X3'), ('+2', 'X4')]
```

Si se necesitan las variables posteriormente puede ser útil esta forma, sino es mas simple la segunda que solo nos da los coeficientes.

Answer (score 1):

Asi puedes hacerlo

```
import re

def extraerValores(listadeEc):
    listacoef = []
    for ecuacion in listadeEc:
        listacoef.append(re.split('X\d', ecuacion)[0:-1])
    return listacoef
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias 

Answer (score 0):

Esto deberia funcionar

```
import re

listaCoefX=['-2X1+1X2-1X3+2X4', '-2X1+2X2-1X3+0X4', '0X1+0X2+2X3-2X4','0X1+0X2+0X3+4X4']

for x in [re.split("X\d", y) for y in listaCoefX]:
    print map(int, filter(None, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución propuesta es usando expresiones regulares:

```
import re

regex = re.compile("(\-|\+)(\d+)|(0)")

listaCoefX=['-2X1+1X2-1X3+2X4', '-2X1+2X2-1X3+0X4', '0X1+0X2+2X3-2X4','0X1+0X2+0X3+4X4']

output = []

for l in listaCoefX :
    r = regex.findall(l)

    f1 = ''.join(map(str, (x for x in r[0])))
    f2 = ''.join(map(str, (x for x in r[1])))
    f3 = ''.join(map(str, (x for x in r[2])))
    f4 = ''.join(map(str, (x for x in r[3])))

    output.append([f1,f2,f3,f4])

print output
```

Genera la siguiente salida:

```
[['-2', '+1', '-1', '+2'], ['-2', '+2', '-1', '+0'], ['0', '+0', '+2', '-2'], ['0', '+0', '+0', '+4']]
```